# Iterate on 1 table to get data from other tableand get combined result from both table

Tags: sql-server, loops

I have 3 tables. The first table 'Status_Mapping' has following columns

```
Status_orignal  Status_Site
accepted        Call Verified
duplicate       Duplicate Leads
dq              DQ
```

Now the other table 'Lead_transaction' has the columns

```
Lead_transaction_id   Rate   Status
  11               0.01   accepted
  12               0.02   accepted
  13               0.01   dublicate
```

and then there is a 'Lead_Instance' table with

```
Lead_Instance_id   Lead_transaction_id   product_id  affiliate_id
 1                    11                   6            10
 2                    12                   7            11
 3                    13                   6            10
```

What I want to do is loop through the status_mapping table and get the count(lead_isntance_id) and sum(rate) for each status and then site status from the previous table with product_id = 6 and affiliate_id = 10
My End result should be like

```
Total              Sum   Status
 1                 0.01   Call Verified
 1                 0.01   Duplicate Leads
 0                 0.00    dq
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This is a basic `join` and `group by` query.

Comment: Since I have to sum and count,and also get other status from the table, it is not working with the joins

Comment: If something "isn't working with joins" it is a flaw in your code since that is the way to do what you are asking. If you can post some more details we can help here. Probably the easiest is just to create a fiddle at sqlfiddle.com

Comment: `looping` in SQL is a code smell, I have *very rarely* needed to loop through any data, in fact, I can't recall the last time it happened.

Answer (score 2):

First, understand that you're not "looping", rather you're joining similar datasets:

```
SELECT  S.Status_Site AS [Status], 
        ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN L.Status IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END), 0) AS [Total Occurrences], 
        ISNULL(SUM(L.Rate), 0) AS [Rate Sum]
FROM Status_Mapping S
LEFT OUTER JOIN Lead_Instance L
    ON S.Status_Original = L.Status
GROUP BY S.Status_Site
```

EDIT:

If you want to use coalesce:

```
SELECT  S.Status_Site AS [Status], 
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN L.Status IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END), 0) AS [Total Occurrences], 
        COALESCE(SUM(L.Rate), 0) AS [Rate Sum]
FROM Status_Mapping S
LEFT OUTER JOIN Lead_Instance L
    ON S.Status_Original = L.Status
GROUP BY S.Status_Site
```

Since you said you've never heard of COALESCE before (all it does is take the first non-null value in the list):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

Comment: But how do I make sure that total occurance and rate sum shows up as 0, if the status is not present for them, so I have to return all the rows fom status_mapping table

Comment: use a `LEFT join` and `coalesce` null values to 0

Comment: Ok, you're changing your requirements and should've included that in your original post.  I will update my answer, but @xQbert is correct.

Comment: Can you please give me the query, I have never used coalesce before.

Comment: @Garima I updated my answer again.  Please accept this answer and upvote it if it helped you.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I'm still having issues, I just found out that I also need to have another join with other table but I'm trying to figure it out. Thanks again

Comment: @stanshaw: The stored proc was not working for me, also I have edited the question for the new requirement. Please, sorry for unaccepting the answer and hope you can help me with new requirement

Comment: @Garima it's pretty bad form to post a question, get the correct answer, accept it,  - then to edit your question adding additional requirements and unaccepting the answer.  What you should do is either post a new question - or edit your answer and leave a comment ***without unaccepting*** the answer.

Comment: @Garima Especially after you have already changed the requirements at least once and gotten help from me every time.  But, best of luck with your new requirements.